# No Breadcrumb settings in Bartik theme?

Tags: breadcrumbs

The breadcrumbs in my Bartik theme work perfectly. However, in my Zen subtheme are skipping a level!

I just noticed that there is no Breadcrumb settings section in the Settings for the Bartik theme.

I am using the Menu Breadcrumbs module for both sites...

Comment: Are these different sites using different themes or the same site using two different themes?  Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry, they are two different sites using different themes.

Comment: check Bartik theme's `template.php` file. settings available here. `function bartik_breadcrumb($variables)`

Comment: Thanks @monymirza 

I have nothing like that in template.php.

I do have the following in my page.tpl.php file though:

      <?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
        <div id="breadcrumb"><?php print $breadcrumb ?><?php if ($title != ""): ?>&raquo; <div class="breadcrumb"><?php print $title ?></div><?php endif; ?></div>
      <?php endif; ?>

Answer (score -2):

Try using [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) instead.

> Allows administrators to set up parametrized breadcrumb trails for any node type. This allows CCK-style node types to have "Home > User Blog > 2005 > January" style breadcrumbs on the node view page itself, synchronizing cleanly with custom views or pathauto aliases. Breadcrumb visibility can be customized via a php snippet.

Comment: Tried that one as well but still no luck :(